# RCP - How to add a Minimize button to a cell of a GRID?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, emf

I'm working on an RCP application. It uses EMF. As per the requirement I got, i'm supposed to add a minimize and maximize button to a cell of a Grid.

Requirement:

The table includes three columns with multiple rows. The first column gives description. Since the content is big and lot many rows , it is challenging to scroll. Hence, the cell initially should show only one line of total text ending with "...", and the cell should have a minimize button and maximize button. Can any one give me understanding about the possibility of this requirement. Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYVEd.png)

Answer (score 0):

The default SWT Table does not support shrinking rows. You could try it with [Nattable](http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/)

It is a SWT implementation of a table. It offers advanced functions such as treeview of a table.